# Hiding Text-Box When It Is Clicked To Be Typed In

Tags: html, css, textbox

Similar to Bing.com's search box, I wanted to make a text box where it looked like there was an image in the text box (i.e. magnifying glass for search engines). Realizing that this is not possible, I decided to make the textbox invisible using CSS, and simply making a blank border around the two. The problem with this approach is that when someone clicks the textbox, an outline of it appears anyway, making hiding it redundant.

How can I make it so that when clicked, the text-box will now show any outline of itself?

Comment: This happens on a lot of browsers anyway, it appears when the box is `focused` on. I'm not sure how to stop that, though; seems to be a browser-specific thing, not something you can just change with css.

Comment: Did you examine Bing's code to see how they did it?  Otherwise, provide a picture of what you want.

Comment: Have you tried setting `outline:0` in your css?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different ways for different browsers.

What i tested so far and it works is with chrome.

html:

```
<input class="noOutline" type="text" />
```

css:

```
.noOutline {
   outline:none;
}
```